# Create an array from two arrays using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a code as following :

```
List<UserDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
UserDTO userDTO;
for (User user : users) {
    for (Individual individual : individuals) {
        if (individual.getKey().equals(user.getIndividualId())) {
            userDTO = new UserDTO();
            userDTO.setUserId(user.getUserId());
            userDTO.setFirstName(individual.getFirstName());
            userDTO.setLastName(individual.getLastName());
            result.add(utilisateurDTO);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write this using Java 8 streams ?

Comment: Wrong algorithm. This is _O(n^2)_ and highly inefficient.  Put one of the sets (either users or individuals) into a `HashMap` and then iterate over the other, looking up the corresponding entry in the map.  Also, you are expected to make an attempt, we are not going to write the code for you.  Try it and ask a specific question when you run into an issue.  Please visit the [help], take the [tour] end read [ask]

Comment: What have you tried? You should start by creating a Map<IndividualKey, Individual> to go from O(n^2) to O(n) (and simplify the code).

Comment: Arrays or ArrayLists?  Your title says "arrays" but your code has `result` as an `ArrayList`.  Also, any attempt you can include in your questions can help us determine where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the keys and values into a map:

```
Map<T, Individual> individualsMap =
                individuals.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Individual::getKey,
                                Function.identity(),
                                (l, r) -> l));
```

where `T` is whatever type `Individual::getKey` is.

Java-8 solution:

```
List<UserDTO> resultSet = 
       users.stream()
            .map(user -> Optional.ofNullable(individualsMap.get(user.getIndividualId()))
                    .map(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, user.getUserId())).orElse(null))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(e -> new UserDTO(e.getValue(), e.getKey().getFirstName(), e.getKey().getLastName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

java-9 solution:

```
List<UserDTO> resultSet = 
        users.stream()
             .flatMap(user -> Optional.ofNullable(individualsMap.get(user.getIndividualId()))
                        .map(i -> Map.entry(i, user.getUserId())).stream())
             .map(e -> new UserDTO(e.getValue(), e.getKey().getFirstName(), e.getKey().getLastName()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This assumes you have a constructor as such:

```
public UserDTO(T userId, String firstName, String lastName) { ... }
```

where `T` should be substituted with whatever type `userId` is.

Comment: In the java 9 solution code, something questions me. You use `Optional.ofNullable()` but then you don't filter non empty optional.  Could you explain that part please ?

Comment: Sure. note that I am invoking stream() upon the optional and that means if the optional is actually empty then an empty stream is returned which then means flatMap will do the remaining work; as if you flatten a stream of say 1 element with another stream of no elements I.e. empty stream the result is a stream of 1 element. In other words you can think of flatMap as discarding the empty Streams which are returned when the optional is actually empty and simply concatenation the Streams with one elements each. @davidxxx

Comment: I understand much better. The `Optional.stream()` introduced in Java 9 (that you have just made me discovered) is the key ! It is indeed very fine because the Java 8 way I used (probably improvable) is very cumbersome : we have to handle explicitly the empty elements of the `Optional`.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but I get this error : `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)` for the Java 8 solution and when I add a `)` I get this error : `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)`

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki for the syntax error you must not have copied the code properly but as for the inference issue, I can't seem to replicate it on IntelliJ IDEA. are you using a different IDE? maybe try using an explicit type for the lambda parameters to `map` i.e. `users.stream().map((User user) -> Optional.ofNullable(individualsMap.get(user.getIndividualId()))
                                .map((Individual i) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, user.getUserId())).orElse(null))...`

Comment: I'm using Eclipse apperently there are some issues with compilation in Eclipse.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki unfortunately, I don't use eclipse one of the reasons being the inference issue, therefore, I cannot really deduce the exact problem, However, my advice is to go through the stream pipeline and explicitly specify the types until the compiler is happy. e.g., use `Optional.<Individual>ofNullable(...)` instead of `Optional.ofNullable(...)`, `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>` to `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Individual, T>` where `T` should be replaced with the actual type of `user.getUserId()` and try changing the last `map` to `.map((AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Individual, T> e) ->` etc.

Comment: Thanks the first suggestion fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but you could try something like that :

```
List<UserDTO> userDtos = 
            users.stream()
                 .map(u -> individuals.stream()
                                       .filter(indiv -> indiv.getKey()
                                                             .equals(u.getIndividualId()))
                                       .findFirst()                                                        
                                       .map(indiv -> new UserDTO(u.getUserId(), indiv.getFirstName(), indiv.getLastName()))
                                       .orElse(null))
                 .filter(Objects::nonNull)                                                         
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`findFirst()` will allow short-circuiting the inner iteration as soon as a matching between an individual and a user is detected.
I introduced an arg constructor in `UserDTO()` to ease its initialization.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in comment by [@JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562027/create-an-array-from-two-arrays-using-streams#comment90090945_51562027), to not go with `O(n^2)` I would like to solve the problem in two steps like this :

```
Map<Long, Individual> individualsMap =
        individual.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Individual::getKey, Function.identity()));

List<UserDTO> result = users.stream()
        .filter(user -> individualsMap.containsKey(user.getKey()))
        .map(user -> {
            UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
            Individual indivd = individualsMap.get(user.getKey());
            userDTO.setUserId(user.getUserId());
            userDTO.setFirstName(indivd.getFirstName());
            userDTO.setLastName(indivd.getLastName());
            return userDTO;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This `individualsMap.get(user.getKey())` can return null I guess.. Maybe add `.filter(user -> individualsMap.contains(user.getUserId()))`?

Comment: @user7 and now? I add a `filter` before I make `map`

Comment: Perfect. Just an opinion. The OP breaks after a first match. If more than one `Individual` can have the same `key`, then you might need to add a merge function to pick the first one. (`(individual1, individual2) -> individual1`). But I don't think it is the case and the break is to stop the unnecessary looping.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm getting this compilation error `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)`